# How can I send an image from an imageview, after taking a picture, to pc via bluetooth?

Tags: android

1. I take photo
2. Photo gets stored in ImageView
3. I want to be able to send that photo stored in the ImageView to my pc via Bluetooth when user selects `Send To Pharmacy` button.

Is this possible?  Since the image is constantly changing, how would I do this?  I have looked up some tutorials and StackOverflow questions but they all seem to be focused on images in a drawable folder already.

But in this case, the image is different every time the user takes a photo.  I just want to know how I can send the current photo that is in the ImageView, and send it to a PC via Bluetooth.  Thanks for any help I appreciate this.

```
    package com.cognizant.expressprescriptionregistration;


    import static android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory;

    public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button bPicButton;
        ImageView imageView;
        String pathToFile;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

            bPicButton = findViewById(R.id.bTakePhoto);
            imageView = findViewById(R.id.imagePrescription);

            // Ask for permission for Camera and Storage
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
                requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // if camera successfully pops up and takes photo, set photo in ImageView
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if (requestCode == 1){
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }

        // Take Picture button onClick listener
        public void takePhoto(View view) {

            setPhotoTaken();

        }

        private void setPhotoTaken() {

            Intent takePhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            // Make sure the app can handle our intent
            if (takePhoto.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                File photoFile = null;

                // Created Photo file
                photoFile = createPhotoFile();

                // Get path of our photo file
                if (photoFile != null) {

                    pathToFile = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Register.this, "com.cognizant.expressprescriptionregistration.fileprovider", photoFile);
                    takePhoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                    startActivityForResult(takePhoto, 1);
                }


            }

        }

        // Create the file where the photo will be stored
        private File createPhotoFile() {

            // Name of file
            String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

            // Location of storage
            File storedDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File photo = null;

            try {

                // Creates file in storedDir
                photo = File.createTempFile(name, ".jpg", storedDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return photo;
        }

        // Send to Pharmacy Button
        public void sendToPharmacy(View view) {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get current image from ImageView by getting the bitmap from ImageView:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

After this you can save and share the bitmap.